# Как правильно возвратить список медиан другого списка

Tags: java, list

В моем коде я хочу найти медиану одного списка и вставить в другой список и удалить значение медианы в изначальном листе, и делать это пока в изначальном списке не останутся значения, по примеру: в листе есть например значения[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], я нахожу медиану по индексу `int median = temp.size() / 2`, в данном случае это 2 и возвращает значение в индексе `2 = 2`, этот индекс со значением удаляется и остается следующие значения в листе `[0, 1, 3, 4]`, тут нахожу медиану, в данном случае `int median = temp.size() / 2` тоже `2`, но у нас четное количество значений, а в этом случае код должен возвратить самое маленькое значение сравнив значение `median` и `median-1`,   сравнив значение 3 и 1 он должен возвратить 1 и так далее...
В моем коде первую медиану находит - `2`, но потом выдает `-1` и не понимаю как решить проблему.
Может неправильно сравниваю значения `temp.indexOf(median) < temp.indexOf(median - 1)`

```
List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList();
        List<Integer> medianTemp = new ArrayList();
int listMedian;
        while (temp.size() != 0) {
            int median = temp.size() / 2;
            if (temp.size() != 1) {
                if (temp.size() % 2 == 0) {
                    if (temp.indexOf(median) < temp.indexOf(median - 1)) {
                        listMedian = temp.indexOf(median);
                        medianTemp.add(listMedian);
                        temp.remove(median);
                    } else {
                        listMedian = temp.indexOf(median - 1);
                        medianTemp.add(listMedian);
                        temp.remove(median);
                    }
                } else {
                    listMedian = temp.indexOf(median);
                    medianTemp.add(listMedian);
                    temp.remove(median);
                }
            } else {
                listMedian = temp.indexOf(median);
                medianTemp.add(listMedian);
                temp.remove(median);
            }

        }
        System.out.println(medianTemp);
```

Comment: Выдавать индексы по спирали: `m, m-1, m+1, m-2, m+2, ...`,  где `m` - индекс медианы. Пример приведен списка нечетной длины. Для списка чётной длины индексация немного другая, идея та же. Если порядок важен, то `m-i`и `m+i` могут меняться местами.

Comment: Если хочется совсем полной свободы при выборе следующей медианы из двух, поддерживайте дырку в середине массива (пара индексов). Следующая медиана на краю дырки, край выбирайте по своему усмотрению. Когда забираете очередной элемент, расширяете дырку. Удалять из массива ничего не надо.

Comment: и какая конечная цель вообще?

Comment: Немного странное определение медианы - в случае четного размера списка должно возвращаться среднее значение:  `(arr[len/2 - 1] + arr[len/2]) / 2`

Comment: В моем случае нет, мне другое надо, чтоб вернуло значение по меньше из двух. Все уже работает сделал.... помогли советы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`temp.indexOf(индекс)` - бесмыссленная конструкция. Вам нужно обратится к элементу списка по индексу. Сделайте так: `temp.get(индекс)`.

Когда вы поправите ваш код, он заработает. Однако его можно улучшить. Если вы знаете что такое О-большое, то понимаете что конструкция `temp.remove(индекс)` тратит линейное время если удаление делается из середины списка. Всего ваша программа потратит квадратичное время на вывод медиан.

Можно обойтись без удаления элементов, если поддерживать "дырку" из ранее удалённых медиан. В коде ниже эта дырка занимает интервал индексов `(l, r)`. Чтобы выбрать следующую медиану нужно сравнить длину оставшихся хвостов слева и справа от дырки. Если они не равны, то нужно вывести элемент из длиннейшего хвоста. Если хвосты равны, сравниваем элементы на краях дырки (индексы `l` и `r`) и выводим меньший.

Как только элемент выведен, соответствующий край дырки подвигается.

Остались мелочи: правильно задать пустую дырку (`l = r - 1`) в начале и вовремя завершить цикл (когда оба хвоста опустели). И добавить обработку пустого списка на всякий случай.

То что получилось работает за линейное время:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


class MedianPrinter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
            list.add(Integer.parseInt(args[i]));
        }

        List<Integer> medians = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int n = list.size();
        if (n > 0) {
            int l = (n - 1) / 2;
            int r = n - n / 2;

            while (0 <= l || r <= n - 1) {
                if (l + 1 > n - r) {
                    medians.add(list.get(l));
                    --l;
                } else if (l + 1 < n - r) {
                    medians.add(list.get(r));
                    ++r;
                } else {
                    if (list.get(l) <= list.get(r)) {
                        medians.add(list.get(l));
                        --l;
                    } else {
                        medians.add(list.get(r));
                        ++r;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (int v : medians) {
            System.out.print(v + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ javac MedianPrinter.java
>
> $ java MedianPrinter 0 1 2 3 4
> 2 1 3 0 4 
>
> $ java MedianPrinter 0 1 2 3 4 5
> 2 3 1 4 0 5
> ```

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснение